# jquery form submit 400 error

Tags: jquery, methods, submit, action

```
function modify_onclick() {     
    var category_no = $("#category_no").val();
    var subclass_no = $("#subclass_no").val();
    var category_name = $("#category_name").val();

    var form = $("<form></form>");
    form.attr('method','post').attr('action','./categoryModify');
    var c_no = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "category_no").attr("value", "category_no").appendTo(form);
    var s_no = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "subclass_no").attr("value", "subclass_no").appendTo(form);
    var c_name = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "category_name").attr("value", "category_name").appendTo(form);
    var oc_no = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "origin_category_no").attr("value", "origin_category_no").appendTo(form);
    var oc_name = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "origin_category_name").attr("value", "origin_category_name").appendTo(form);

    var numbersOnly = category_no;
    if(isNaN(numbersOnly)||numbersOnly<1) {
        alert('it's not a number!!');
        $("#category_no").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {  
        // submit form
        $(document.body).append(form);

        form.submit();
        alert('registered');
    }
}
```

this is my code!. I was changing it from javascript and I met 400 error

The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Answer (score 0):

it was my mistake on .attr("value", "var name") .
I removed "" , so the value could set